# Parsing a nginx conf file for host headers

Tags: bash, nginx, awk, sed

I need help with extracting and then reinserting a specific block of text from a configuration file. The block I am interested in starts with "server_name" and ends with a ";"

```
server_name   example.com  
              www.example.com
              anothername.co.uk;
```

I think sed or awk commands could do this but I am not sure where to start. Ideally I would like to get "example.com" "www.example.com" and "anothername.co.uk" read into a bash array.

I am making a shell script to control a web server and want to be able to edit the host headers for each site, so I want to read in the host headers from the file into an array so that I can prompt the user if they want to delete or add and hosts. Then I want to write the edited host headers back into the file.

Using Jotne's awk command I can now read in the host headers. So It's just writing them back to the file that I need help with.

I didn't realise but there varying amounts of white spaces at the start of each of the lines that I am trying to read in. We have 100's of websites that have been edited manualy in the past.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: please edit your question to include how you want to edit values. Are the searchString and replacementString to be passed in as arguments? Or are you going to edit your shell script each time to want to make an edit. Good luck.

Comment: The example [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample) shows at least 3 `server_name` sections.  Do you want to edit all of them?  Also, that example shows space delimited entries, while your example is space and return delimited.  Which do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
arr=($(awk '/^server_name/ {f=1} f {p=$NF;sub(/;$/,"",p);print p} /;$/ {f=0}' file))
echo ${arr[0]}
example.com
echo ${arr[1]}
www.example.com
echo ${arr[2]}
anothername.co.uk
```

It will get all text starting form `server_name` and ends with `;` into an bash array

Or you can store them in an internal `awk` array, and then write them to another file:

```
awk '/^server_name/ {f=1} f {p=$NF;sub(/;$/,"",p);a[++c]=p} /;$/ {f=0} END {for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i]}' file > newfile
cat newfile
example.com
www.example.com
anothername.co.uk
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realise that we have various amounts of white space at the start of each line but the changing your like as follows seemed to fix this.  "awk '/\s*server_name/ {f=1} f {p=$NF;sub(/;$/,"",p);a[++c]=p} /;$/ {f=0} END {for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i]} somewebsite.conf'

Comment: @user2137455 `/\s*server_name/` is not a good solution. It will match if `server_name` is found with one or more space in front. You could then just do  `/server_name/` to make it work.  Better would be `/^\s*server_name/` to make it start from beginning if line.